# How do I get revenues of companies split into relevant segements from SEC EDGAR?

Tags: sec, edgar

i am looking for a way to get the revenues of companies split into their relevant parts from SEC EDGAR.
For example: If i am looking up AAPL i want to get the revenue in their specific products like iPhone, iPad, Mac, Services and Wearables.
Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Are they publishing that?

Comment: I think you would have to get this from the company, if it's published at all.

Comment: @littleadv they publish it in their Q4-notes. Its not a standardised field but most of them show how the revenue is distributed over the segments and regions.

Comment: That's your answer, then.

Answer (score 0):

Obtaining revenues of companies split into relevant segments from the SEC EDGAR (Electronic Data Gathering, Analysis, and Retrieval) database involves several steps. Here's a general guide on how to do this:

Access the SEC EDGAR Database:

Go to the SEC EDGAR website (https://www.sec.gov/edgar).
Use the search feature to locate the specific company you're interested in.
Find the Company's 10-K Filing:

In the search results, locate the most recent "10-K" filing for the company. The 10-K is an annual report that contains detailed financial information.
Access the 10-K Filing:

Click on the link to the 10-K filing to access the full document.
Navigate to the Financial Statements:

Within the 10-K filing, you'll typically find a section labeled "Financial Statements" or something similar. Click on this section to access the company's financial data.
Locate the Segment Reporting Information:

Look for the segment reporting information within the financial statements. This section provides details on the company's revenue broken down by different segments or business units.
Review the Segment Disclosures:

Examine the notes to the financial statements, particularly the notes related to segment reporting. Companies are often required to provide explanations and breakdowns of their revenue by segments in these notes.
Analyze the Data:

Carefully review the segment reporting data to obtain the revenues split into relevant segments. This information should include revenue figures for each business segment, such as geographical regions or product lines.
Download and Save the Data:

If needed, you can download the relevant sections of the 10-K filing or copy the data for your analysis or reference.
Additional Resources:

Consider using third-party financial data providers or analysis tools that specialize in extracting and presenting financial data from SEC filings. These tools can simplify the process and offer additional features for financial analysis.
Verify and Cross-Reference:

Always verify the data you extract from SEC filings and cross-reference it with other sources or financial reports for accuracy and completeness.
It's important to note that the availability and format of segment reporting information may vary from one company to another. Additionally, segment reporting requirements may change over time, so ensure that you are using the most up-to-date and relevant information for your analysis.

Comment: I believe OP is wanting to use the _data_ api to get granular revenues, not just to find the annual report and look it up themselves.

Comment: Also this feels somewhat ChatGTP-ish